# Change dimensions of JButton

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, dimensions

I have problem with this. The button is taking up the entire JFrame. I've tried changing the dimensions of the JFrame and the JButton but with no changed. It's completely hiding a JTable underneath. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
JFrame FRAME = new JFrame();
  JButton BUTTON = new JButton("OK");
  FRAME.add(new JScrollPane(TableName));
  BUTTON.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,30));
  FRAME.add(BUTTON);
  FRAME.setSize(700, 600);
  FRAME.setVisible(true);
  FRAME.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The default layout manager for a a `JFrame` is a `BorderLayout`. You are attempting to add two component the `CENTER` which is not allowed. Only the last one added will be displayed.

You need to specify constraints when adding components to a `BorderLayout`. Your code should be something like:

```
  frame.add(new JScrollPane(TableName), BorderLayout.CENTER);
  button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,30));
  frame.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Also, variables names should NOT be upper cased. Follow Java convention.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples. The tutorial code will also show you how to better structure your program so you follow Swing coding conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the button straight to the frame, create a JPanel first, add the button to the panel then add the panel to the frame.

Answer (score -1):

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    // frame.setBounds(x axis, y axis, weight, height)
    frame.setBounds(10,10,304,214);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    button.setBounds(98, 75, 126, 39);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: (1-) Don't use a null layout for too many reasons to list here. There is absolutely no reason to do this. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.