# Why doesn't my Combobox update its color properly?

Tags: java, swing, colors, combobox, background

I am implementing a dark mode into my program and everything works just fine, except a Combobox, which doesn't want to change its color as I want.

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [bilder-upload.eu](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/thumb/184949-1570543075.png))</sub>

So as you can see, the "popup" of the Combobox changes the color just fine, but the Combobox itself doesn't. Also the Foreground color of the Combobox changes, but the background not.

I guess, the Look and Feel might cause the issue.

In my main-class:

```java
UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() );
```

Where I change to Darkmode:

```java
TeamInterface.userFilterComboBox.setBackground( darkBackgroundColor );
TeamInterface.userFilterComboBox.setForeground( fontColor );
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( TeamInterface.userFilterComboBox );
```

I have to use the updateComponentTreeUI-Method, because otherwise the "popup" also remains white.
If I remove the look and feel in my main-class, the combobox looks good,as you can see in this picture,

[image: 2]
<sub>(source: [bilder-upload.eu](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/thumb/786bfe-1570544791.png))</sub>

but I doesn't want to get rid of the system look and feel, so I tried to manually edit the UI of the combobox to metal with this code :

```java
userFilterComboBox.setUI( new MetalComboBoxUI() );
```

but.. the result is just awful, even thoe theoretically (at leats thats what I think) it should look the same as without look and feel

[image: 3]
<sub>(source: [bilder-upload.eu](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/cf28f2-1570545072.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Combobox not is a component only to the background and the foreground but is the complex component.
An example:JComboBox is composed to:

- ArrowButton
- List of itme
- Border (and it have a color)
- the item selected

So for change all you can add inside your UIManager, all constant or you can define a new UIComponent.

So an *PersonalComboBoxUI* can the following:

```
/**
 * @contributor https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo
 */
public class PersonalComboBoxUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {

    public static ComponentUI createUI (JComponent c) {
        return new PersonalComboBoxUI ();
    }

    @Override
    public void installUI (JComponent c) {
        super.installUI (c);

        JComboBox<?> comboBox = (JComboBox<?>) c;
        comboBox.setBackground (UIManager.getColor ("ComboBox.background"));
        comboBox.setForeground (UIManager.getColor ("ComboBox.foreground"));
        comboBox.setBorder (UIManager.getBorder ("ComboBox.border"));
        comboBox.setLightWeightPopupEnabled (true);
    }

    @Override
    protected JButton createArrowButton () {
        Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon ("ComboBox.buttonIcon");
        JButton button;
        if (icon != null) {
            button = new JButton (icon);
        }
        else {
            button = new BasicArrowButton (SwingConstants.SOUTH);
        }
        button.setOpaque (true);
        button.setBackground (UIManager.getColor ("ComboBox.buttonBackground"));
        button.setBorder (BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    protected ListCellRenderer createRenderer() {
        return new MaterialComboBoxRenderer();
    }
}
```

You should be defined also the PersonalComboBoxRenderer

```
/**
 * @contributor https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo
 */
    public class PersonalComboBoxRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent (JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JComponent component = (JComponent) super.getListCellRendererComponent (list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

            component.setBorder (BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder (5, 5, 5, 5));
            component.setForeground (UIManager.getColor ("ComboBox.foreground"));
            component.setBackground (isSelected || cellHasFocus ?
                    UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.selectedInDropDownBackground") :
                    UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.background"));

            return component;
        }
    }
```

ps: in this case, I'm using the UIManager.put("ComboBox.background", COLOR) for add and stratification inside the JComponent.

So I want to add two information regarding if you using the personal color inside the UIManager or the PersonalComboBoxUI the color should be defined with this code

```
Color PINK_400 = new ColorUIResource (236, 64, 122);
```

because when you go to remove look and feel the color couldn't remove but if you used *ColorUIResource* the look and feel should be removed correctly.

To finish, if you do not have needed the default look and feel, I want to suggest you use a library.

The **material-UI-swing** has a system theming for creating the personal timing in your app and the all theme is personalizable.

This is the repo [vincenzoapalazzo/material-ui-swing](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing) and [atarw/material-ui-swing](https://github.com/atarw/material-ui-swing) are the same repository and the same developer so, the **vincenzopalazzo/material-us-swing** is the developer branch, an contains more fix and test.

An example of the library is

[image: OcenicTheme].

Ps: I am the designer of the *MaterialTheming System*.

Comment: Nice man thanks a lot, it just works fine, except that the Arrowbutton is a little bit too big (https://www.bilder-upload.eu/thumb/d4575d-1570701680.png)  I tried to edit the button in the createArrowButton, but it doesn't seem to work if I try to set the Buttonssize a certain value, any idea why ?

Comment: I think the button is the problem, try to set `Icon icon = null` inside the method `createArrowButton`

Comment: Nope thats not it, the button always gets created with the new BasicArrowButton(),because the else-case get called

Comment: So, if in the your UIManager configuration not is the Icon, so can you change the dimension of arrow button, for change dimension use this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812260/change-dimensions-of-jbutton

Comment: ps: The button not is always created with BasicArrowButton but is created with an arrow button because inside your UIManager configuration not is present the Icon of JComboBox. for experience I recommend using custom icons because you have more control over what you do. maybe you have an increase in configuration but my timing system simplifies this